# Mobile application not working properly

Tags: java-me, netbeans-7

I did a mobile application on java using Netbeans IDE.

It's working fine when I run in my system.

Problem is when I try to install it in my mobile its getting error like application error.

Can anyone help me find what went wrong?

I am using Sony mobile and in that it's getting "Application Error" nothing more then that, and even I try to install in another mobiles also it's getting like "error". I can't find what type of error it is.

Comment: are you using any constant in your class file which was declared in one class and you are using that in another class.

Comment: what error are you having .. they can be so many errors .. memory , size , exception etc ...

Comment: @Baba 

Error is when u installing in system its getting application error ...

in the system its works fine

Comment: @Ramteja_abhim You need to share *the actual error*. How do you expect us to guess?

Comment: @AndrewBarber  Thing is in the mobile i'm not able to install ... so i cant find any error in the mobile, when i try to install in it its getting like application error .... in the system when i run its good no error i found in the system ...

Comment: @Ramteja_abhim You need to *post that "like application error" here* Why aren't you understanding this? We need to know **what** the error is. We can not guess!

Comment: @AndrewBarber  im also not understanding what the error is ... 

im using sony mobile and in that its getting "application error" nothing more then that, and even i try to install in another mobiles also its getting like "error" i cant find wt type of error it is

Comment: You need to be more specific. Are you saying that it is *literally* saying "Application Error"? Because that's not what you actually said... you said it was **like** "Application Error". "Like" means that it was similar to - not that it was exactly.

Comment: sry its not like application error 

its "Application Error"

Comment: you are likely to be using the wrong MIDP version ... try it on another phone and lets see

Comment: Removed down-vote due to clarification that it is literally saying "Application Error". Language barrier issue!

Answer (score 6):

You have to first check that APIs which you used in your application is supported in your phone or not. If APIs are not supported by your phone then it give error at installation time. And yes also check that your phone supported MIDP and CLDC version.

Answer (score 2):

Ok it is very silly problem. When you create Java ME Application with Netbeans, by default it uses MIDP 2.1 Version. and I am sure your device supports MIDP 2.0 ( happened with me few times ). Just change your MIDP Version from 2.1 to 2.0 in NetBeans and then create .Jar file and try again, it will surely work.

Comment: Thank u 

i changed it but still its not working getting same error